# Strange error showing up in laravel logs

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, subdomain

I have a site built with Laravel 5.2, and everything is running smoothly, but I keep seeing this in my logs:

> 'ErrorException' with message 'Route [baldeaglecontracting.home] not
>   defined

The way I have my routes configure, this means someone is trying to hit a baldeaglecontracting subdomain on my site like baldeaglecontracting.mydomain.com

What I can't figure out is, why would someone be trying to hit this same subdomian on my site over and over again?

Comment: A web crawler maybe? For example in my webmaster tools panel, I've seen Googlebot try to index some pretty weird URLs that don't really exist and are not referenced anywhere on my domains. Check your HTTP server logs to see where do the requests originate from.

Comment: That makes sense. Just seems really specific for a web crawler, but the Internet is a weird place :)

Comment: Yeah, given that according to some studies more that 60% of internet traffic is generated by robots (crawlers, scrapers, hacking tools, etc) experiencing weird traffic is not as weird as one might think :).